# Rails conditional association on instance itself

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, ruby-on-rails-5, rails-activerecord

Let's say we have a `Comment` that is connected to an `Article` through a belongs_to association. Comment has an attribute called `is_connected` which is a boolean.

I know that it's possible to add a condition to the belongs_to relation. Is it possible to add a condition on the instance itself?

```
class Comment
  belongs_to :article, -> {where: is_connected: true}
end
```

Like in this example - is_connected is referencing the article model. But I want the relation to only exist if `comment.is_connected == true`

Comment: The syntax is wrong, you can use normal ActiveRelation methods in that block, so: `-> { where(is_connected:true) }`

Comment: Sorry, misread your question, the code example was confusing. You can add conditions on the fly, so you could add a class method to Comment, names self.article, in which you conditionally make the relationship if the comment.isconnected. I'll try to draft an example as an answer.

Comment: I'm having some doubts whether you are approaching this correctly. Isn't it better to make the belongs_to optional, and just check whether `comment.article.exists?`, that way you don't need to manage a separate field in your table to indicate whether the relationship exists.

Comment: @bo-oz - thanks for your reply. i really have to make the distinction. the example should only clarify what I'm trying to do.

Comment: As per @Akshay's doubt, what does `is_connected` do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can define a conditional validation:

```
belongs_to :article, optional: true
validates :article, presence: true, if: :is_connected
```

Optionally also:

```
validates :article, absence: true, unless: :is_connected
```

---

Alternatively, if you want the association to still be populated, but behave as if it's not, then you'll need to define a custom method:

```
def connected_article
  is_connected ? article : nil
end
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure why do you have this approach. I mean if a comment has article_id present in it then you can safely say that this comment is associated with an article. `is_connected` seems like duplication. `article_id` present/absent works the same way.